# C# passing parameters by reference confusion

Tags: c#, oop

After reading some articles still confused. Why changing the value of the StringBuilder would change and value of DateTime doesn't ? Both are reference types as I understand:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime myDt = DateTime.MinValue;
        Change(myDt);
        Console.WriteLine(myDt);

        StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder();
        y.Append("hello");
        Foo(y);
        Console.WriteLine(y);

        String test = "hello";
        Foo(test);

    }

    public static void Change(DateTime dt)
    {
       dt.AddDays(24); 
       //or dt=dt.AddDays(24);
    }

    static void Foo(StringBuilder x)
    {
        x.Append(" world");
    }

    static void Foo(String x)
    {
        x = x + " world";
    }
}
```

Comment: [`DateTime.AddDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) will not change the DateTime, it returns a **new** `DateTime` where [`StringBuilder.Append`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.append.aspx) modifies this instance.

Comment: @How about the String ? It doesn't change the String either.

Comment: @Chuchelo: a [String is immutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).

Comment: Note though: Having a parameters of a reference type is not the same thing as passing a parameter by reference. You can pass both reference and value types both by reference (using `ref` and - to some degree - `out`) and by value (the default; in the case of reference types it means copying the reference).

Comment: @delnan, helpful elaboration, now i seem to have clear understanding. thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) isn't a reference type, it's a structure, which means a value type.

Answer (score 5):

[`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) is a value type (a struct) that cannot be modified. It is not a reference type.

When you call a method that appears to change a struct, it often really returns a brand new struct, without modifying the original because the original cannot be modified (it is immutable). Although the same applies to strings, strings aren't value types; they're reference types which have been designed to be immutable, hence the need for classes such as `StringBuilder`.

Also, passing reference types as parameters is not the same as passing parameters by reference using [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) or [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

[DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) is a structure, so it's a **value** type.

So like any other value type it's past *by value* (copied in practise) and only after injected into the function stack.

Answer (score 1):

A [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) is a struct - hence a value type.
Strings are immutable reference types.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned the difference is in a Class (which StringBuilder is) and a Struct (which DateTime is). Here are some articles to further help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471(v=vs.71).aspx

A good understanding of structs versus classes is important in OOP, and particularly c#